# Integrate $\int_{1}^{\infty} 3^{-n}dn$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How can one do the following:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} 3^{-n}dn$$

My incorrect solution:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-n \ln\\3}dn = -3^{-n}\ln3$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

For $a>0,$
$$\dfrac{d(a^x)}{dx}=\dfrac{d(e^{x\ln a})}{dx}=a^x\ln a$$

$$\int a^x\ dx=\dfrac{a^x}{\ln a}+K$$ where $K$ is an arbitrary constant

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\int_{1}^{\infty}3^{-n}\ dn$$
$$=\lim_{a\to \infty}\int_{1}^{a}\left(\frac13\right)^{n}\ dn$$
$$=\lim_{a\to \infty}\left[\frac{\left(\frac13\right)^{n}}{\ln \left(\frac13\right)}\right]_{1}^{a}$$
$$=\lim_{a\to \infty}\left[-\frac{1}{3^{n}\ln 3}\right]_{1}^{a}$$
$$=\lim_{a\to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{3\ln 3}-\frac{1}{3^{a}\ln 3}\right]$$
$$=\left[\frac{1}{3\ln 3}-0\right]$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3\ln 3}}$$

Comment: So the answer to $\int 3^{-n} dn$ is $\frac{3^{-n}}{ln3} + C$ OR $\frac{3^{-n}}{-ln3} + C$?

Comment: $\frac{3^{-n}}{-\ln 3}+C$

Answer (score 1):

Using the way you tried to approach ($a>0$) $ \int a^x dx=\int e^{\ln(a^x)}dx=\int e^{ x \ln(a)}dx=\frac{1}{\ln(a)}e^{x \ln(a)}+C=\frac{1}{\ln(a)}e^{\ln(a^x)}+C=\frac{1}{\ln(a)}a^x+C \\ \\ $ $\int 3^{-n} dn=\int e^{\ln(3^{-n})} dn=\int e^{- \ln(3) n} dn=\frac{1}{-\ln(3)} e^{-\ln(3) n}+C=\frac{-1}{\ln(3)}e^{\ln(3^{-n})}+C=\frac{-1}{\ln(3)}3^{-n}+C$

Comment: So the answer to $\int 3^{-n} dn$ is $\frac{3^{-n}}{ln3} + C$ ?

Comment: Should have negative in front of that. I will add this specific case to my answer.